# calulate particular table cell's summation using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am working with jQuery. I want to calculate particular table cell's summation using jQuery. My code is here:

```
 <table id="table">
<tr>
    <td>Item1</td>
     <td>Item2</td>
     <td>Item3</td>
     <td>Item4</td>
     <td>Item5</td>
     <td>Total</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="1"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="2"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="3"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="4"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="5"/></td>
     <td><input type="text" /></td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="1"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="2"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="3"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="4"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="5"/></td>
     <td><input type="text" /></td>

</tr>
```

I want the sum of the second and the fourth column and displayed in the last column for each row (i.e. `item3+item5` and the result will be displayed in the total column).
How can it be done using `for each` loop using jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#table tr").each(function(){
        var a = $(this).find("td:eq(2)").find("input").val();
        var b = $(this).find("td:eq(4)").find("input").val();
        var c=parseInt(a)+parseInt(b);
        $(this).find("td:eq(5)").find("input").val(c);
    });
});
```

See Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8e5qkhp6/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a change handler like

```
//register the change handler only for 3rd and 5th input elements
$('#table').find('td:nth-child(3) input, td:nth-child(5) input').change(function () {
    var $inputs = $(this).closest('tr').find('input');
    $inputs.last().val((+$inputs.eq(2).val() || 0) + (+$inputs.eq(4).val() || 0))
}).filter('td:nth-child(5) input').change(); //to initialize values
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nz9qggL6/)